# Compute volume of tetrahedron using a triple integral

Tags: integration, volume

I'm trying to compute the volume of a tetrahedron with the vertices (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (2, 0, 0), (0, 2, 0). It needs to be done using a triple integral. Not allowed to use "det" or other functions.

I think first I need to find a plane equation using those 4 points right? But how do I do that?

Comment: Could you show us that you've put effort into trying to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the plane containing the points  $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,1)$ is given by $x+y+2z-2=0,$ that is, $z=1-\frac x2-\frac y2.$ Note that the basis of the tetrahedron is a triangle, one side on the $OX$-axis, one side on the $OY$-axis, and the equation of the third one is given by $x+y=2.$ Thus, the volume can be obtained by evaluating the integral

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x} \left(1-\frac x2-\frac y2\right)dydx. $$

We have:

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x} \left(1-\frac x2-\frac y2\right)dydx=\int_0^2 \left(\left(1-\frac x2\right)(2-x)-\frac{(2-x)^2}{4}\right)dx \\ =\int_0^2 \left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)dx. $$

Comment: Nice it works. Can you explain why z = 1 - x/2 - y/2? I don't quite understand that part.

Comment: Once you have the equation of the plane $x+y+2z-2=0$ you need to get the function to integrate. That function is $z=z(x,y).$ You have:  $x+y+2z-2=0\implies  x+y+2z=2\implies 2z=2-x-y\implies z=\frac22-\frac x2-\frac y2=1-\frac x2-\frac y2.$

Comment: How did you get the equation of the plane? Is there a certain method/technique you use to calculate it?

Comment: The equation of a plane trough three points $(x_1,y_1,z_1),$ $(x_2,y_2,z_2),$ $(x_3,y_3,z_3),$ is given by $$\left|\begin{array}{rrr}x-x_1& y-y_1&z-z_1\\x_2-x_1& y_2-y_1&z_2-z_1\\x_3-x_1& y_3-y_1&z_3-z_1\\\end{array}\right|=0.$$