# Triple integral using tethahedron

Tags: integration

I have 4 dots (0,0,1) , (1,0,1) , (0,3,1) , (0,0,3)

I want to calculate tetahedron with a **triple integral**.
The problem is that, I can't seen to find a way to build this tethahedron.

What I need is this.  $\iiint E y dV $       (The big $E$ represents the tethahedron)

And I also have a plane equation that uses 3 of the dots  that I have in here:
$$2x + 2y+ 3z = 5$$

I need to find the numbers to integrate but I cant seen to find a way to do this.  Any help ?

Comment: What does the plane equation have to do with the region?

Comment: The letter a of the question asked to find that, I assume there is something to do with it. But I really dont know

Comment: As is, the question is very unclear... does the plane cut the region? Is the integrand the equation of the plane? Something else?

Comment: I think it cuts because the plane was made with the same points, i think that i have to use it to calculate the thing. But that's the problem, I dont know how to buil the figure with te dots i been given.

Comment: Is the integral  $\iiint_Ey\,\mathrm{d}V$?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just did not know how to format properly

Comment: As you can see, only one of the points lies on the plane -- namely, $(1, 0, 1)$ -- so I have no idea what the point of the plane is.

Comment: But it is also impossible for these four point to lie on one plane. For if they did, then we would have some equation $ax + by + cz = d$ such that $c = d$ by plugging in $(0, 0, 1)$and $3c = d$ by plugging in $(0, 0, 3),$ from which it follows that $c = 0.$ We would then have that $d = 0$ by plugging in$(0, 0, 1)$ again, from which it follows that $a = 0$ by plugging in $(1, 0, 1)$ and $3b = 0$ by plugging in $(0, 3, 1).$

Comment: Well that's what i think so. But the question is, forget the plane how would I calculate the integral with the tetahedron ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958548/compute-volume-of-tetrahedron-using-a-triple-integral?rq=1   I need something like this, but I cant understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the tetrahedron with four vertices $(0, 0, 1),$ $(1, 0, 1),$ $(0, 3, 1),$ and $(0, 0, 3).$ Observe that this tetrahedron can be described as the region bounded by the planes $z = 1,$ $x = 0,$ $y = 0,$ and $6x + 2y + 3z = 9.$ (Use the fact that the normal vector to the bounding plane defined by the points $(0, 0, 3),$ $(1, 0, 1),$ and $(0, 3, 1)$ is $\mathbf n = \langle -1, 0, 2 \rangle \times \langle 0, -3, 2 \rangle$ to find this fourth plane.)

Based on this, the region $E$ can be described as $x$-, $y$-, or $z$-simple, so the triple integral can be easily computed. For instance, one way to compute it is via the $z$-simple interpretation $$\iiint_E y \, dV = \int_0^1 \int_0^{-3(x - 1)} \int_1^{3 - 2x - \frac 2 3 y} y \, dz \, dy \, dx.$$